# ¿Con qué usuario debo iniciar sesión para clonar mi base de datos?

Tags: mysql, lamp

Resulta que estaba por clonar mi base de datos, (había iniciado sesión con el nombre de usuario de la base de datos que quiero clonar), pero al momento de poner.

```
CREATE DATABASE espocrmclon;
```

Me apareció lo siguiente

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'spectraespocrm'@'localhost' to database 'espocrmclon'
```

Por lo que entonces pregunto:

1. ¿Con qué usuario debo iniciar sesión para clonarla?
2. ¿El `'@'localhost'` para qué es?, ¿es muy necesario?. Ya que en el tutorial que seguí solo venia tal cual así:

   CREATE DATABASE clon_ddbb;
3. ¿Qué hacer para que todo salga correcto?

Answer (score 1):

Mas bien no es cual usuario debas usar sino que el usuario tenga permisos para crear base de datos.
Si deseas hacer el cambio conforme a tu pregunta, con el usuario de root puedes hacerlo.

Si quieres usar el usuario que mencionas tendrías que entrar con usuario root y usar la siguiente sintaxis

```
grant CREATE DATABASE to spectraespocrm;
flush privileges;
```

Luego inicias sesión con **`spectraespocrm`** y podrás crear tu base de datos.

Comment: Y cual es mejor? crearla como usuario root u otorgar los privilegios?

Comment: Disculpa quise entrar como super usuario para después otorgar los permisos y me salió esto:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATABASE to spectraespocrm' at line 1

Comment: Una disculpa, quita la palabra database de la primera línea.
Cual es mejor? pues lo recomendable es que no uses root, mas que para cosas específicas, como administrar permisos o crear usuarios con super permisos XD
Incluso desde ahí puedes administrar el uso de recursos del motor de base de datos conforme al servidor, entre otras cosas